# JS Promise Ignored (not sure)

Tags: javascript, function, promise

I am working on an alert-similar function in javascript, and I got in trouble.
The code of the first function (prepBkCrt) looks like this:

```
function prepBkCrt() {
    event.preventDefault();
    crtBkMnl = true;
    crtBkCnl = false;
    const url = crtBkTab.querySelector("#url");
    const name = crtBkTab.querySelector("#name");
    if (name.value.length >= 17) {
        poper("Bookmark","I will pass this part",true).then((response) => {
            if (response === false) {
                crtBkCnl = true;
                hideBkTab();
                return;
            }
        });
    }
    addBookmark(url.value,name.value);
    if (crtBkCnl === false) {
        poper("Bookmark","Bookmark successfully created!",false);
    }
    url.value = "";
    name.value = "";
}
```

and the second function looks like this:

```
function poper(headerTxt, descTxt, option) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const poper = document.querySelector("#poper");
        const header = poper.querySelector("h2");
        const buttonDiv = poper.querySelector("div");
        const desc = poper.querySelector("span");
        header.innerText = headerTxt;
        desc.innerHTML = descTxt;

        const yBtn = buttonDiv.querySelectorAll("button")[0];
        yBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {poper.style.transform = "translateY(-300px)"; resolve(true);});
        
        const nBtn = buttonDiv.querySelectorAll("button")[1];
        nBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {poper.style.transform = "translateY(-300px)"; resolve(false);});

        if (option === false) {
            nBtn.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            nBtn.style.display = "block";
        }

        poper.style.transform = "none";
        setTimeout(() => {poper.style.transform = "translateY(-300px)"; resolve(false);},10000);
    });
}
```

This used to work well on other code, but it seems to not work on this javascript file. I've checked that it ***does*** run the first `poper` function in `prepBkCrt` function, which is the problem. The expected behavior is if the `name.value`'s length is over 17, it should run `poper` function (it should work like  [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qD9Nq.png), and run [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jR6Vq.png), but the code only runs the second image. What's the problem?

Comment: Try to add a else block for name.value.length check.

Comment: I have trouble understanding the issue: `poper()` is not being run ? or when it's being run you are not getting the expected behavior?

Comment: Or try to add the code below the first poper inside another then. This is based on your requirement.

Comment: "*if the `name.value`'s length is over 17, it should run `poper` function*" - which one? There are two calls to `poper`, and currently it's running *both* at once.

Comment: @Bergi  the first one.

Comment: @geauser the first call of `poper` is not working- it seems.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy your answer doesn't work.. I think the problem is related to the first call of `poper`.  I've added code `console.log("It works")` below `if (name.value.length >= 17) {...}`, and the console logs "It works". I think it is the problem of calling function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for an `else` statement. The `return` inside the `.then()` callback does not break from `prepBkCrt`.

```
function prepBkCrt() {
    event.preventDefault();
    crtBkMnl = true;
    crtBkCnl = false;
    const url = crtBkTab.querySelector("#url");
    const name = crtBkTab.querySelector("#name");
    if (name.value.length >= 17) {
        poper("Bookmark","I will pass this part",true).then(response => {
            if (response === false) {
                crtBkCnl = true;
                hideBkTab();
            }
        });
    } else {
        addBookmark(url.value,name.value);
        poper("Bookmark","Bookmark successfully created!",false);
        url.value = "";
        name.value = "";
    }
}
```